# Mesh disappears when activating dyntopo

Tags: mesh, sculpting

Using Blender 2.8

My mesh is slightly edited and disappears when activating Dyntopo. However a current workaround is to add an empty mesh and join your broken mesh into that one. After that you can sculpt it as normal.

If anyone has a clue why this happens I'd like to know more.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. For me, the problem was with the visibility of the individual geometry components (vertices, edges, or faces). Please make sure to enter edit mode, select all components, hide selection, then unhide again.

Hope this solves the problem for you too!